# IPN PAYPAL - Invalid Tests

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Currently, I test the paypal transaction via the wordpress plugin eshop. Everything works fine between my test website and the Paypal Sandbox. I received the amount of each transaction on my test paypal account.

So, is there anybody to explain why, in my IPN log, I saw this kind of message?

```
[09/16/2013 12:17 PM] - FAIL: IPN Validation Failed.
IPN POST Vars from Paypal:

IPN Response from Paypal Server:
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 12:17:12 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=44VS0oE0w9OKqQXm8_tt1vtbJvdnyOujOdaUKmL1YKFVv2fNtrpwZwLBrbXK2cj1hl4rsZsNkbdK1rYEiWVjJVoDpdtpsQU3C9TlmnyeNPuIQIGzN5pnm1txc-zdooQbYBGoEe_cDYBNgIPU16TPpvtCYBTcLZ720155oY1ososuqpBRYu-KcG2qifDzzMkZVDADM6CZu3SSvGklgKgVOqxIb15FtRPLMepSn0re190FNP-12fh8TcLc44kBTBja1ZPI__GWGtkVWAweinGCtdtky6ebYrHqjZvD0dtsfoMyhx0XE07tPXfKL2FmQMUnE7ghjcySUFuCTVjZfcNiDGcCkn9EaQZ-DvIhL8X4aT6c1FvqNR3vjnRokP6neuGRAiu9hpn6Br7sp4UJhU3pEaoRK2G76FC1x6dBXTtX-7qud2MV_IGGom_q8Li; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Thu, 14-Sep-2023 12:17:12 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Sun, 11-Sep-2033 12:17:12 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.1379333832493873; path=/; expires=Wed, 09-Sep-43 12:17:12 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dslingshot%26TIME%3D3371578962; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.128.11.1379333832485619; path=/; expires=Wed, 09-Sep-43 12:17:12 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

7
INVALID
0
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The data being sent back to PayPal must not match what PayPal originally sent.  When this happens they won't verify it.

Make sure that if you're using the sandbox for the purchase you're also hitting the PayPal sandbox for IPN verification and visa versa.  Also, make sure you've got all of the original data included just as it was sent to you.